Zookeeper Error - server is not starting upon the using zookeeper-server-start.bat with the required properties file as input
I am trying to execute the following command:
zookeeper-server-start.bat ....\config\zookeeper.properties
while being inside the kafka\bin\window directory
and while running the command I am getting the following error:
zookeeper-server-start.bat ....\config\zookeeper.properties
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
I downloaded the apache file, then I edited the zookeeper.properties file.
I created a mklink folder called kafka, for the downloaded kafka_2.12-3.7.0 folder.
then I tried to run the following command:
zookeeper-server-start.bat ....\config\zookeeper.properties
while being in the kafka\bin\windows directory
